# Sql addition query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

If the sum of a group comes as negative. The negative numbers are to be increased (biggest negative first) to bring the total sum as 0

Example

Group 1 has this 4 values
-4,-3,1,1

The total is negative

Thus it gets tweaked to

0,-2,1,1 .

-4 becomes 0 as it is the highest negative..

the balance is removed from -3 to make it to -2..

Thus the total is 0.

Can anybody please help in this

Comment: It's an interesting question. Could please you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example table (as opposed to list) of numbers? I'm assuming you're grouping rows, and summing across multiple rows, but we should discuss with a concrete example of your input and expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added a few extra values to make sure I'm covering some edge cases.

The idea here is to look at the rolling sum, and figure out the point where the sum of the negative values goes past the overall sum. Before that point, the newvals are 0, after that point, they're the original value, and at that point, it's the difference between the rolling sum and the overall sum.

```
with vals as (select * from (values (1), (-3), (1), (-4), (-5), (-6), (2)) v(val))
, 
ordered as
(
select v.val
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by v.val) as rownum
    , sum(v.val) over () as OverallTotal
from vals v
)
,
rollingsum as
(
select o.*
    , sum(case when o.val < 0 then o.val else 0 end) over (order by o.rownum rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as RollingSumNegsByRownum
    , sum(case when o.val < 0 then o.val else 0 end) over (order by o.rownum rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as RollingSumNegsByRownumPrev
from ordered o
)
select r.val
    , case 
        when r.OverallTotal < 0 and r.val < 0 and r.OverallTotal <= r.RollingSumNegsByRownum then 0
        when r.OverallTotal < 0 and r.val < 0 and r.OverallTotal < r.RollingSumNegsByRownumPrev and r.OverallTotal > r.RollingSumNegsByRownum then r.RollingSumNegsByRownum - r.OverallTotal
        else r.val
    end as NewVal
from rollingsum r
;
```

Results:

```
-6  0
-5  0
-4  -1
-3  -3
1   1
1   1
2   2
```

And results on the original list:

```
-4  0
-3  -2
1   1
1   1
```

Comment: Thank you...this is very helpful